# Pass req,res from index.js to another js file in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module.exports

[I am using express for node].

I encountered a code where the form-data is being posted into `index.js` but it has to be processed in another javascript file. I debugged the original code at nearly every step but at this point I am stuck.

Here are the relevant parts in the files.

`index.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const proctor = require('../controllers/proctor');

router.post('/myform', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("hello");
  proctor.function1;
});
module.exports = router;
```

`proctor.js` (not written by me)

```
exports.function1 = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
}
```

`app.js`

```
var indexRouter = require('./server/routes/index');
app.use('/', indexRouter);
module.exports = app;
```

So, console shows "hello", but not the `req.body` so the second js file is not being called at all. The `proctor.js` is not my code and I think I need to import `index.js` maybe to get it working.

The file tree is

```
app.js
server
   controllers
      proctor.js
   routes
      index.js
```

Comment: where have you called `function1` function?

Comment: @Yousaf edited...

Comment: you have to use this  `airTicketsController` instead of `proctor.function1`

Comment: `proctor.function1;` - did you meant to write: `proctor.function1(req, res);`?

Comment: @Ashutoshpatole well, edited. I tried to use dummy names for easy look

Comment: @Yousaf something like that but writing that exactly give error `proctor.function1' is not a function.

Comment: Try adding the file extension: `'../controllers/proctor.js'`

Comment: @Yousaf Although the suggestion was correct but didn't solved the problem. I think that I have to pass req, res to the function call.

Comment: @Yousaf Combination of your two suggestions solved the problem. **you can add an answer**. I was importing the `module.export`(non-existent) instead of the file and that's why function was not being called and gave error when passed parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a token of closing the question, since the original answerer is not adding the answer.

1. `const proctor = require('../controllers/proctor');` imports the object exported by the `proctor.js` file. But in this case, we have to use

   `const proctor = require('../controllers/proctor.js');`

   to be able to call the functions present in `proctor.js`
2. I was not passing the arguments to the function call. So, I would have to do

```
router.post('/myform', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("hello");
  proctor.function1(req,res,next);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your anonymous function with proctor.function1 like this

```
router.post('/myform', proctor.function1);
```

Change proctor to

```
module.exports = {
  function1: (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
  }
}
```

Comment: But then there was an error that `Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]`

Comment: The original code was like your suggestion only, but I edited it remove these errors

Comment: Does this file exist? Console.log it - const proctor = require('../controllers/proctor')

Comment: Yes this file exists and all the routes are correct as in another piece of this code, I had created a database connection in `proctor.js` and queried it in `index.js` and the database query worked.